# How to register same mongoose hook for multiple methods?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-middleware

I want to execute same script in the pre-hook with multiple methods like this:

```js
UserSchema.pre("findOne", function(next) {
    console.log("Common code");
});
```

&

```js
UserSchema.pre("findOneAndUpdate", function(next) {
    console.log("Common code");
});
```

So, as you can notice in the above 2 scripts that they both are executing the same code but have different methods: `findOne` & `findOneAndUpdate`.

So, is there any way to register both pre-hooks with the same code all at once?

Answer (score 5):

You can pass all the methods in the form of an array as the first argument in pre/post hook methods, like this:

```js
UserSchema.pre(["findOne", "findOneAndUpdate"], function(next) {  // ["method1", "method2", "method3"...]
    console.log("Common code");
});
```

And now you can register & execute the same script for multiple methods.