# How to register same mongoose hook for multiple methods in TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-middleware

Based on the answer in [How to register same mongoose hook for multiple methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67268004/how-to-register-same-mongoose-hook-for-multiple-methods)

```
const hooks = [ 'find', 'findOne', 'update' ];

UserSchema.pre( hooks, function( next ) {
    // stuff
}
```

The code above works fine when not using TypeScript in strict mode. As soon as I enable strict mode, it complains: `No overload matches this call.`

How can I adjust the code to fix this? I can't seem to find much documentation about it, most documentation just offers examples of how to do it for a single method instead of multiple at a time.

Comment: The inferred type of `hooks` is `string[]`, something more specific (explicit type of `MongooseQueryMiddleware[]`, `as const`, ...) might be helpful so the compiler knows what the _values_ are.

Comment: Yes, adding "[ ... ] as MongooseQueryMiddleware[]" seems to fix it. Could you post your suggestion as an answer?

Comment: Note the last section of my answer - don't use the type assertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inferred type of your `hooks` variable is `string[]`. `Schema.pre` has [various overloads](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/7971a4dbd55888f0b005e65b06024109af8352f7/types/index.d.ts#L328-L348):

```js
    /** Defines a pre hook for the model. */
    pre<T = THydratedDocumentType>(
      method: DocumentOrQueryMiddleware | DocumentOrQueryMiddleware[],
      options: SchemaPreOptions & { document: true; query: false; },
      fn: PreMiddlewareFunction<T>
    ): this;
    pre<T = Query<any, any>>(
      method: DocumentOrQueryMiddleware | DocumentOrQueryMiddleware[],
      options: SchemaPreOptions & { document: false; query: true; },
      fn: PreMiddlewareFunction<T>
    ): this;
    pre<T = THydratedDocumentType>(method: 'save', fn: PreSaveMiddlewareFunction<T>): this;
    pre<T = THydratedDocumentType>(method: 'save', options: SchemaPreOptions, fn: PreSaveMiddlewareFunction<T>): this;
    pre<T = Query<any, any>>(method: MongooseQueryMiddleware | MongooseQueryMiddleware[] | RegExp, fn: PreMiddlewareFunction<T>): this;
    pre<T = Query<any, any>>(method: MongooseQueryMiddleware | MongooseQueryMiddleware[] | RegExp, options: SchemaPreOptions, fn: PreMiddlewareFunction<T>): this;
    pre<T = THydratedDocumentType>(method: MongooseDocumentMiddleware | MongooseDocumentMiddleware[] | RegExp, fn: PreMiddlewareFunction<T>): this;
    pre<T = THydratedDocumentType>(method: MongooseDocumentMiddleware | MongooseDocumentMiddleware[] | RegExp, options: SchemaPreOptions, fn: PreMiddlewareFunction<T>): this;
    pre<T extends Aggregate<any>>(method: 'aggregate' | RegExp, fn: PreMiddlewareFunction<T>): this;
    pre<T extends Aggregate<any>>(method: 'aggregate' | RegExp, options: SchemaPreOptions, fn: PreMiddlewareFunction<T>): this;
    pre<T = M>(method: 'insertMany' | RegExp, fn: (this: T, next: (err?: CallbackError) => void, docs: any | Array<any>) => void | Promise<void>): this;
    pre<T = M>(method: 'insertMany' | RegExp, options: SchemaPreOptions, fn: (this: T, next: (err?: CallbackError) => void, docs: any | Array<any>) => void | Promise<void>): this;
```

As the error message tells you, *none* of these accepts `string[]` as the `method` argument, because there are plenty of valid string values that are **not** valid method names.

However if you are more specific about your intentions, e.g. using the [query middleware type](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/7971a4dbd55888f0b005e65b06024109af8352f7/types/middlewares.d.ts#L4):

```js
  type MongooseQueryMiddleware = 'count' | 'estimatedDocumentCount' | 'countDocuments' | 'deleteMany' | 'deleteOne' | 'distinct' | 'find' | 'findOne' | 'findOneAndDelete' | 'findOneAndRemove' | 'findOneAndReplace' | 'findOneAndUpdate' | 'remove' | 'replaceOne' | 'update' | 'updateOne' | 'updateMany';
```

you can satisfy the compiler (and get the values checked for any typos, e.g. it could tell you if `findone` was accidentally used instead of `findOne`):

```js
import { type MongooseQueryMiddleware } from "mongoose";

// ...

const hooks: MongooseQueryMiddleware[] = ["find", "findOne", "update"];

UserSchema.pre(hooks, function (next) {
    // stuff
});
```

Alternatively, you could just inline the array:

```js
UserSchema.pre(["find", "findOne", "update"], function (next) {
    // stuff
});
```

---

Note that using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions), as suggested in your comment above, is **not** the right way to go about this. When you do that, rather than letting the compiler check the values you insist to it that they're right, so it can't catch typos for you:

```js
const hooks = ["find", "findone", "update"] as MongooseQueryMiddleware[];
                    // ^^^^^^^^^

UserSchema.pre(hooks, function (next) {
    // stuff
});
```

Comment: Yes, I just did the type assertion to quickly test if it would work. I didn't plan on implementing it like that :)